# Avoid submit after add new field

Tags: css, forms, laravel-blade

When I try to add a new form field, hit enter button work as submit instead. What am I doing wrong and how do I prevent such behavior?

```html
 <div class="container bring-to-front">
            <div class="shadow rounded p-5 bg-contrast overflow-hidden">
                <div class="section-heading text-center">
                    <h2 class="heading-line">Add data in the fields</h2>                
                </div>
    
                <div class="mx-auto position-relative form-wrapper">
                    <form method="post" id="form" action="{{route('randomize.store')}}" name="form" 
                    class="form text-center" data-response-message-animation="slide-in-left" novalidate>
                       @csrf
                        <div id="parent" class="list-group">
                            <div class="form-group form-filed horizontal">
                                <input name="data1" class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
                                placeholder="add some data"  autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)' 
                                onkeydown="pressEnter(event)" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="parent" class="list-group">
                            <div class="form-group form-filed horizontal">
                                <input name="data2" class="input" type="text" autocomplete="off" 
                                placeholder="add some data"  autofocus onkeypress='validate(event)' 
                                onkeydown="pressEnter(event)" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-alternate align-center">Draw</button>                   
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `event.preventDefault()` handy in your pressEnter() function:

so your function should look like::

```
function pressEnter(event){
event.preventDefault();

// and your other codes go here

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the submit button is supposed to work as it should, but when I press the Enter button, the problem follows as described. I've added your suggestion, but now the submit button doesn't work, and adding fields with the Enter button doesn't work either, but it's not a surprise to me. How can I improve it?

Comment: @j.sadne ive edited my answer, hope that makes sense to you?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use this feature, but it doesn't work, probably because I don't know how to put it in the code.

Comment: I don't know which file it's supposed to be exactly, there's a lot of it. I'm very beginner, that's why it's causing me so many problems.

Comment: I finally managed to find a place where I should put the javascript code, in public folder. Your code works. Thank you for your interest and help.

Comment: my pleasure to have helped.